# Why doesn't this code to convert a std::array to a std::string not display anything?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, casting

I'm using this template to change my `std::array` to a string.  Why doesn't it print out anything?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

template<std::size_t N>
std::string to_string_2(std::array<char, N> const& arr) {
  const char* str = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(arr.data());
  return std::string( str, str+N );
}
int main()
{
   std::array<char, 16> state = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,11,12,13,14,15,0};
   std::cout << to_string_2(state) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Is std::tr1::array the same as std::array?

Comment: So, `1` should be converted to `'1'`, and `15` should be converted to ...?

Comment: @JamesBlack, It's the precursor to it. `std::tr1::array` was implemented while C++11 was still having finishing touches put on it. When C++11 was finished, it got promoted into `std`. We have TR2 coming with C++14.

Comment: @chris - Thank you, I had no idea about this precursor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are creating an array of characters with numeric values between 1 and 16.  These are non-printing characters, so you shouldn't see anything.

Try changing their values to characters that do display, like 'A', and see if this resolves the issue.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

What makes you think it doesn't print out anything? I would guess that it does print out characters with ACSII codes from your original array, but they just happen to correspond to "invisible" characters on your platform, i.e. to characters that are not represented by a visible glyph on the screen.

You can redirect your program's output to a file and then open that file in a hex editor. I'm sure you will immediately discover your character code sequence in that file.